# uppercase lowercase bug..web dev

Tags: dojo

Hi I am facing a weird bug, I am writing a tag like

```
<div id="thecontent" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane"></div>
```

Please see the "T" in dojoType it is in uppercase.Now I go and see my page not rendered properly, so I view source  and I find that the source is correctly shown, but when I check firebug , I get this:-

```
<div id="thecontent" dojotype="dojox.layout.ContentPane"></div>
```

Please notice that t in dojotype here it is small. I went ahead and changed the entire dojotype to UpperCase , but it is still rendered as lower case.

I even checked in other browsers, and it is the same. Has someone faced anything like this. If so please tell me how to handle this.

I am tired of this.

{update:-Please find attached a screenshot of wireshark when I do a refresh.. unable to understand a thing}[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a packet sniffer such as Wireshark will tell you if it's a server-side or client-side problem.

Comment: How can it be a server side problem, as when i right click and view source on the template I get the propercaps..and it is happening in only this template.. everything else is ok

Comment: Something between the source and the HTTP connection may be modifying it.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.. I just updated a screenshot of wireshark after doing a refresh.. I dont understand a thing .. would appreciate any help..

Comment: The bottom part should have a tree control of sorts for viewing the data. Open the bottom one and click on the last line. This should be the returned HTML page. Scroll down on the bottom pane until you see the piece of HTML that you're interested in and examine the attribute there.

Comment: The attribute is perfectly fine there Ignacio. It is not all lowercase.I mean it is just the way I put it there "dojoType"

Comment: Then it's the browser's fault that it's doing that. You now no longer have a web dev bug, but rather a browser issue.

Comment: how can all firefox,chrome and opera have a bug all at the same time

Comment: Probably because they're all trying to do the same thing, normalize the HTML.

Comment: Yeah just solved it... thanks for your help, yes they were all trying to normalize the HTML...as far as dojoType issue was concerned, I had missed out adding the dojo.parser.parse(). I am really sorry to have wasted your time. And thanks for being patient